# Creating grids with UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

All, 
I need to create a grid of UIViews, in another square UIView (which is bigger). So I want to create UIViews of x=20,y=20 which will make a grid in a UIView.

I know how to create a UIVew programatically in swift, for example :

```
let rectangle = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 20, 20))
        rectangle.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.view.addSubview(rectangle)
```

but whats the best way to add this UIView to another UIView and NOT the main one.

So I have the main UIView which covers the screen and a smaller one which is for the grid and then I want UIViews to make the grid ?

Any help would be brilliant, and better than me making over a hundred UIIViews in IB.

Comment: Use a `UICollectionView`  Far and away the best solution for creating a grid layout.

Comment: can you put it as the answer please and i will approve it

Comment: BTW, not sure what the title has to do with the question :)

Comment: Made a bit of a mistake... will try and ammend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `UICollectionView.` Far and away the best solution for creating a grid layout.